# Explain `core.reducers` library in layman's term

Tags: clojure

I'm currently learning `clojure` for fun and today I run into this [article about reducers](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html). I find it not only interesting but tricky to me. As a beginner:

1. I know how to use core `map`, `filter`, `reduce`
2. I understand that `core/map`, `core/filter`... return a `sequable`col
3. Rich Hickey mentioned `core.reducers/map`... return a `reducible` col

Because the implementation of `core/map`... and `core.reducers/map`... look very identical. My question is

1. How does `reducible` col make difference in layman's term?
2. Can anyone give me some trivial examples of `reducible` function?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

For me, the main idea of reducers is that they actually do **less** than `map`/`filter`/`reduce`. Reducers do not specify if they execute lazily or eagerly, in serial or in parallel, on a collection or on another type of data structure and what they produce may be a collection or something else. Examples:

1. `map`/`filter`/`reduce` **must be passed a collection and must produce a
   collection**; a reducer does not have to do either. This idea of reducers is
   extended in [transducers](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2014/8/6/transducers-are-coming) so that the same transducer can applied to either
   a collection or a `core.async` channel.
2. Reducers also do not specify **how** they are executed.
   `map`/`filter`/`reduce` always execute in a serial manner across a
   collection; never in parallel. If you want to execute across a
   collection in parallel, you must use a different function: `pmap`. You
   could imagine that if you wanted to filter in parallel, you could
   also create a function `pfilter` (this doesn't exist but you could write it).
   Instead of creating a parallel version of each function, reducers simply say
   "I don't care how I'm executed" and it's up to another function (`fold`
   in the case of reducers) to decide if the execution should be done in parallel or not.
   `fold` is more general than `pmap` because the reducers that it applies to can
   do filtering or mapping (or composed to do both).

In general, because reducers make fewer assumptions about **what they apply to**, **what they produce** or **how they are applied**, they are more flexible and therefore can be used in a wider variety of situations. This is useful because reducers focus on "what your program does" rather than "how it does it". This means that your code can evolve (e.g. from a single thread to a multi thread or even to a distributed application) without having to necessarily touch the part of the program that forms the core logic of what your code does.

Comment: tks @optevo, that's great sum up, but yours hasn't answered how `reducible`function work in `core.reducers` and can you make an example of that?